# Pentaho webpage at 8080 extremely slow

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, pentaho

Tried increasing the jvm space by following these instructions:

Go to `/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/bin/` directory and run the `./shutdown.sh` command to stop the appropriate server.

Change the directory to `biserver-ee/tomcat/scripts`.

Edit the `ctl.sh` file.

Locate the line under start tomcat, which looks like this:

```
export JAVA OPTS="-Dpentaho.installed.licenses.file=/opt/pentaho/.installedLicenses.xml -Xms128m Xmx768m -XX-MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dyc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

Set the memory to a minimum of `4096 M` and a maximum of `6144 M`, depending on your computer's memory capabilities.

Start the Tomcat server or service.

but in vain.

The pentaho is running on linux EC2 m3 large. The box is under utilized, still webpage is very slow and eventually not opening at all.

I uninstalled pentaho and tried re-installing again, it gave warning of could not start BA server. I didn't remove the weka files folder.

Please suggest!

Comment: Are you running a report or are all pages slow?

Comment: The welcome page is taking lot of time to load. So I uninstalled pentaho, however now I am facing a new problem, java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080. The pentaho summary settings had a different port this time. ./shutdown-server.sh is also not working. How do I make sure that nothing is running on 8080 or any other 80 port?

Comment: if you deleted the folder without shutting down the server first, you must kill the process (using "kill"), then you can proceed to reinstall